# Countable and uncountable in one word?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> [original question] Do any words words exist that are a countable and an uncountable noun at the same time?

- Are there any nouns that are both countable and uncountable?
- Are there any words which are uncountable and uncountable at the *same* time?

Comment: Here is a good list with notes on usage: https://www.englishclub.com/ref/Nouns_that_are_Count_and_Noncount/

Comment: As discussed before, some usages (A soft light suffused the glade) seem to exhibit both count (taking an indefinite article) and non-count (*Two soft lights suffused ...) properties at once. I'd say this is gradience rather than hybridism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among other things, just about any liquid could be a countable and uncountable (mass) noun in the same word. Take beer, for example.

> Give me some beer. [mass noun]
>
> Give us five beers. [count noun]

Comment: "I'll have a carbon tetrachloride, please, plus three more for my friends here".

Comment: @ErikKowal: "D'ye want water back, sir?"

Answer (score 3):

Almost anything normally uncountable - certainly it applies to most food items - can be made countable if one uses a simple plural as an alternative to ***varieties of***. e.g. *There are countless cheeses (Varieties of cheese), whiskies, wines, beers, yoghurts, breads, meats, hams, etc.*

It can also apply as substitute in the case of ***bottles of***, ***jars of***, ***cups of*** etc. *Five beers is too many! How many whiskies has he drunk? Two coffees please.*

Answer (score 0):

The nouns which can be countable or uncountable depending on the context are originally pluralia tantum, i.e. uncountable. But they can be used in singular if there is a portion of the substance referred by the noun.

> The sun was blazing and there was no pool in view. He dreamed of a motel and a barman who could give him a water.
>
> > Mother always told her daughter that carbonated drinks are harmful but she would always order a coke having a snack in a cafe.

Comment: In the first context I would rather opt for *He was dying for **some** water* rather than *a [glass of] water*.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: But if there *had* been a pool, there might have been poolside attendants and other staff. In which case instead of dying of dehydration, he could simply have gasped *"Waiter! Bring me **a** water, please!"*.

Comment: Yeah, some water might be better. But as for the pool, the word denotes primarily a natural reservoir of lentic water.

Comment: I might say *a water* now. :) A pool can be any body of water, but usually we tend to think of a swimming pool.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: A puddle can be a good substitute to the pool then, I guess.

Comment: I would say "*There was* **no water** *in sight, and he dreamed of a bartender serving him* **an iced water**". But Robusto's answer is much better, because it's clearer the difference between C and U (or "mass"). Here, *water* covers springs, lakes, oases, rivers, streams, that one might see in nature, and man-made sources such as taps, faucets, fountains etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was once told that nouns are either countable or uncountable.  Then I learned that some nouns can be used as both countable or uncountable. Now, I don't think I have encountered a so-called uncountable noun that cannot also be used as a countable noun. Sometimes this involves a change in meaning (the speed of *light*; the *lights* on my Christmas tree; Time flies; how many times have I told you that?), sometimes it means *a kind or serving of uncountable noun* (*a coffee*, *a beer*).

Comment: How about "Call **driver** to pick me up"? "Call **some driver**" means some specific driver, not a continuously variable quantity of driver.

Comment: In your first sentence, I think you are using a singular count noun without an article in an instruction/demonstration/recipe type setting. *Dip **cookie** in milk.* Either that or you gots  plane badd English. @Ben

Comment: I mean that "driver" doesn't want to be treated as a mass noun. (It _could_ done in extraordinary circumstances, though. Maybe I heard it done once, ago December…) Then again, your point was the other way around.